# Change Fluent API mapping dynamically

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, azure-sql-database

Our project uses Entity Framework Code First. We wish to have an instance where a very simple POCO represents many tables in the database. It is part of a horizontal partitioning strategy in SQL Azure. SQL Azure does not support file groups, thus it does not support typical partitioning. There are going to be a very large numbers of tables, so using a UNION ALL view as a partitioned view via CHECK CONSTRAINTs on the base tables will not be feasible.

Thus, we would prefer to peform the mapping as needed at runtime. However, this occurs in the OnModelCreating event of the DbContext class via code such as

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityName>().ToTable("foo", "bar");
```

. Is it possible for us to perform this mapping inside a factory? We would prefer to supply metadata to the factory and have it use the Fluent API then, rather than have a one-to-one mapping between POCO and table via the ModelBuilder.

Comment: It is not clear what you ask for. You can always have custom code creating mapping in your `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: I don't want to define it in OnModelCreating. I want to have one class, and be able to dynamically map that class to several tables that have the same schema. If I do it in OnModelCreating, I do not believe I have that option. Using OnModelCreating out of the box makes you map to one and only one table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a constructor to your `DbContext` derivative, having two string arguments for table name and metaschema name. You can store the names in member variables and use them in the `ToTable` method.

The `DbModel` is created when it is actually needed, so the constructor always runs before the `OnModelCreating` event. (This is not always the case in derived classes, but that's a different topic).

As an optimization you can cache compiled `DbModel`s and build `DbContext`s by [the constructor accepting a `DbCompiledModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679391%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: I like this idea. Thank you. What if I want custom mapping for more than one entity? I suppose I could pass a Dictionary<string, string> to contain all of the mappings, using EntityName as the key and TableName as the value. Your thoughts?

Comment: Sure, you could do that. Or `Dictionary<type, string>` to make it more type-safe.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. I'll let this thread simmer a bit and see what develops. I like your answer.