# Is there a way to query against multiple tables with the same table design dynamically with Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an outdated data warehouse that wasn't property designed.  Unfortunately, because of some restraints, I can't redesign the entire database, so I am working with multiple tables that hold information for a specific year.  I'll need to query against 3 of the tables at a time (3 different years for today's date on each year).  Is there a way to create this query without knowing the tables being used until run-time?  I'm trying to do this in Entity Framework since the application is being ported over to ASP.NET MVC 3, but I've only used Entity Framework when the tables are static.

Below is an example of the table structure I am working with.

Tables:

```
INFO2008
INFO2009
INFO2010
INFO2011
INFO2012
```

All tables use the same table design:

```
ID (INT)
FirstName (VARCHAR)
LastName (VARCHAR)
ZipCode (VARCHAR)
Date (DATETIME)
```

Now, if I today's date was 1/1/2012, I would need a query that would pull a count of all rows on 1/1/2012 from INFO2012, 1/1/2011 from INFO2011, and 1/1/2010 from INFO2010.  Each table only holds that year's list of records.  So the table name (with year) would need to be figured out dynamically at run-time.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this using the following:

    Context.CreateQuery<EntityObject>(String.Format("SELECT VALUE t FROM {0}", "INFO2011"));

This way I can switch out the INFO2011 to whatever current table year I need to pull the results from.  Also, using this, I can dynamically add ObjectParameters to the SQL statement as well.  

To access the fields on a view, I created an interface that all entities inherit so that even though we don't know the table we are using in the view, the interface will allow me to pull values out of any of the tables since they all share the same design.

Comment: Hi, could you put your solution in an answer and mark it as accepted (which you can do two days later)? You may like [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762808/change-fluent-api-mapping-dynamically) too, by the way.

Comment: Thanks GertArnold.  That is another great solution.  I will take a closer look at it before I decide the best way to implement this into my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using the following:

```
Context.CreateQuery<EntityObject>(String.Format("SELECT VALUE t FROM {0}", "INFO2011"));
```

This way I can switch out the INFO2011 to whatever current table year I need to pull the results from. Also, using this, I can dynamically add ObjectParameters to the SQL statement as well. To access the fields on a view, I created an interface that all entities inherit so that even though we don't know the table we are using in the view, the interface will allow me to pull values out of any of the tables since they all share the same design.