# C# - choose Entity and variable LINQ/query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I'm in the process of using C# to build a file download service - part of the process validates the download from one or more databases and provides details of the download.

There are four databases the validation process could call - it really depends on which service the download is for. The databases are either MSSQL or MySQL and can either use stored procedures (of a complex type) or a LINQ query with several joins. All results will contain the same column information.

I have defined the databases within the Entity Framework and I'm happy with the code in a single instance - if I query a different database I don't want to write the code again that does the same task.

I have searched for several hours trying to find a solution that enables me to specify the entity and query to use based on a condition and and keep it strongly typed.

For the stored procedure query I am using code like this:

```
using (myEntity1 ctx = new myEntity1())
{
    var results = ctx.MyStoredProcedure(param1, param2);

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

For the LINQ query I can using code like this:

```
using (myEntity2 ctx = new myEntity2())
{
    var results = (from t in ctx.table select new { t.Col1, t.Col2,});

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, I want to be able to specify the entity and query based on a number of conditions. I also want the result to be strongly typed. It seems simple enough but I cannot find an answers that works.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762808/change-fluent-api-mapping-dynamically) looks a bit like what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another year of non-stop learning, if I were doing this now I would probably use a repository to load each dataset into its POCO then project these POCOs into one I actually wanted, perhaps using this extension method:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{

    public static ProjectionExpression<TSource> Project<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
    {
        return new ProjectionExpression<TSource>(source);
    }

    public static string GetSQL<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
    {
        return source.ToString();
    }
}

public class ProjectionExpression<TSource>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Expression> ExpressionCache = new Dictionary<string, Expression>();

    private readonly IQueryable<TSource> _source;

    public ProjectionExpression(IQueryable<TSource> source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }

    public IQueryable<TDest> To<TDest>()
    {
        var queryExpression = GetCachedExpression<TDest>() ?? BuildExpression<TDest>();

        return _source.Select(queryExpression);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> GetCachedExpression<TDest>()
    {
        var key = GetCacheKey<TDest>();

        return ExpressionCache.ContainsKey(key) ? ExpressionCache[key] as Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> : null;
    }

    private static Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> BuildExpression<TDest>()
    {
        var sourceProperties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties();
        var destinationProperties = typeof(TDest).GetProperties().Where(dest => dest.CanWrite);
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "src");


        var bindings = destinationProperties
                            .Select(destinationProperty => BuildBinding(parameterExpression, destinationProperty, sourceProperties))
                            .Where(binding => binding != null);

        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TDest>>(Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(TDest)), bindings), parameterExpression);

        var key = GetCacheKey<TDest>();

        ExpressionCache.Add(key, expression);

        return expression;
    }

    private static MemberAssignment BuildBinding(Expression parameterExpression, MemberInfo destinationProperty, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> sourceProperties)
    {
        var sourceProperty = sourceProperties.FirstOrDefault(src => src.Name == destinationProperty.Name);

        if (sourceProperty != null)
        {
            return Expression.Bind(destinationProperty, Expression.Property(parameterExpression, sourceProperty));
        }

        var propertyNames = SplitCamelCase(destinationProperty.Name);

        if (propertyNames.Length == 2)
        {
            sourceProperty = sourceProperties.FirstOrDefault(src => src.Name == propertyNames[0]);

            if (sourceProperty != null)
            {
                var sourceChildProperty = sourceProperty.PropertyType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(src => src.Name == propertyNames[1]);

                if (sourceChildProperty != null)
                {
                    return Expression.Bind(destinationProperty, Expression.Property(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, sourceProperty), sourceChildProperty));
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static string GetCacheKey<TDest>()
    {
        return string.Concat(typeof(TSource).FullName, typeof(TDest).FullName);
    }

    private static string[] SplitCamelCase(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, "([A-Z])", " $1", RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim().Split(' ');
    }
}
```

http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code